# Guardar datos en un documento .txt

Tags: c++

tengo que guardar varias partidas en un documento txt, he conseguido que guarde una partida de esta forma.

```
3
4 OCA
5 POSADA
15 PUENTE1
17 OCA
19 DADO1
20 CARCEL
21 OCA
24 LABERINTO
27 PUENTE2
29 OCA
32 OCA
35 CALAVERA
36 POZO
38 OCA
42 OCA
43 DADO2
44 OCA
47 OCA
50 OCA
53 OCA
58 OCA
63 OCA
1
1 0
1 0
```

El primer número es un contador de las partidas guardadas, no se como implementar que vaya aumentando desde el 1 hasta un máximo de 10 partidas que se pueden guardar en el archivo. Lo demás es el tablero de juego, el turno del jugador que le toca y las casillas y penalizaciones de los jugadores, en este caso están en la primera casilla, sin penalizaciones. Necesito guardar más partidas en el documento, pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo.

char abandonar;

```
    cout << "Quieres guardar la partida? SI/NO: ";
    cin >> abandonar;
    if (abandonar == 'S' || abandonar == 's') {
        partida.turno = cambiaTurno(partida.turno);
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_JUGADORES; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_CASILLAS; j++) {
                juego.partidas[1].tablero[j] = partida.tablero[j];
            }
            juego.partidas[1].estadoJug[i].casilla = partida.estadoJug[i].casilla;
            juego.partidas[1].estadoJug[i].penalizaciones = partida.estadoJug[i].penalizaciones;

            if (i == partida.turno) {
                juego.partidas[1].turno = i + 1;
            }
        }

        
        guardaPartidas(juego);

        return -1;
        break;
```

partidas y juego son tipo struct, que guardan lo que es cada casilla, donde esta el jugador y si tiene penalizacion alguna.

```
typedef enum { NORMAL, OCA, PUENTE1, PUENTE2, POZO, POSADA, LABERINTO, DADO1, DADO2, CARCEL, CALAVERA } tCasilla;

typedef tCasilla tTablero[NUM_CASILLAS];

struct tEstadoJugador
{
    int casilla;
    int penalizaciones;
};

typedef tEstadoJugador tEstadoJugadores[NUM_JUGADORES];

struct tEstadoPartida {
    tEstadoJugadores estadoJug;
    tTablero tablero;
    int turno;
};

struct tListaPartidas {
    tEstadoPartida partidas[MAX_PARTIDAS];
    int contador;
};
```

La idea es que tiene que comprobar si existe un archivo que se llame como le dices y si existe, añadir una nueva partida y cambiar el contador a 1 mas.

Comment: Entendí que necesitas guardar más partidas, pero aún no me queda claro el problema. ¿`partidas` es un arreglo y te estás quedando corto? ¿Tienes el mismo problema con `estadoJug`? ¿O qué?

Comment: Puedes poner un carácter para marcar el final de cada partida pir ejemplo *,
así cuando leas este carácter significa que ahí empieza otra partida

Comment: @Mateo, he editado la pregunta para que se entienda un poco mejor, creo. Si se te ocurre alguna forma de resolverlo te agradeceria que me la comentases. :)

Answer (score 0):

He logrado añadir mas partidas a un mismo documento de texto usando:

```
ofstream archivoEd(nombre, std::ios::app);
     
    if (archivoEd.is_open()) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_PARTIDAS; i++) {
            if (partidas.contador == i) {
                archivoEd << partidas.contador;
                guardaTablero(partidas.partidas[1].tablero, archivoEd);
                archivoEd << partidas.partidas[1].turno << endl;
                guardaJugadores(partidas.partidas[1].estadoJug, archivoEd);
                archivoEd.close();
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "NO SE PUDO GUARDAR EL ARCHIVO" << endl;
    }
```

Ahora solo me falta ver como añadir el contador el parte de arriba que vaya sumando en funcion de las partidas guardadas.

Comment: ¿Esto responde tu pregunta de alguna forma? Sino considera editar la pregunta en lugar de crear una respuesta.